# Binary search for students

Tags: c++, performance, binary-search

I'm putting together an example for students where I would like to show how we can optimize even such basic algorithm like a binary search with respect to hardware. I do not consider threads. I wrote it in C++ and the whole example can be found [here](https://github.com/RadimBaca/binary-search). I'm trying to show some examples of the prefetching.

**Test data** If we would like to see the effects of the optimizations proposed in the following examples, then it is necessary to use data that are not in the CPU cache.

We are going to test it using some code like this

```
// arr - array with at least 100MB of values
// test_arr - array with values that we are going to search in arr
// test_count - size of the test_arr
for (auto i = 0u; i < test_count; ++i) {
   auto position = binarySearch(item_count, arr, test_arr[i]);
}
```

*Size* - If the `arr` array is significantly larger then largest CPU cache then most of the array won't be stored there and we will inevitably experience the L2 cache misses during the run. L2 cache misses are slow and it will become the major bottleneck of our binary search algorithm.

*Randomness* - It is better to have data in the `test_arr` that accesses the `arr` randomly, otherwise, the basic binary search algorithm will benefit from data access locality.

Please note that the L2 cache misses can be experienced even on a small array in some complex algorithm which works with a lot of data. In other words, we need a large array only for the purpose of testing, but the optimization can be useful everywhere where expect the binary search to happen on a data outside of CPU cache.

**The basic algorithm** It is something along these lines:

```
using Type = int64_t;
int binarySearch_basic(size_t item_count, const Type arr[], int search)
{
    int l = 0;
    int r = item_count - 1;
    while (l <= r) {
        int m = l + ((r - l) >> 1);
        if (arr[m] == search) return m;
        if (arr[m] < search) l = m + 1;
        else r = m - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Prefetch** The first optimization simply try to prefetch possible memory in advance

```
int binarySearch_basic(size_t item_count, const Type arr[], int search)
{
    int l = 0;
    int r = item_count - 1;
    while (l <= r) {            
        int m1 = arr[l + ((r - l) >> 2)]; // new code 
        int m2 = arr[r - ((r - l) >> 2)]; // new code 

        int m = l + ((r - l) >> 1);
        if (arr[m] == search) return m;
        if (arr[m] < search) l = m + 1;
        else r = m - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**More items per iteration** The second optimization is a little bit more sophisticated. It accesses more than one item per iteration which allows read more relevant data per CPU L2 cache miss wait.

```
int binarySearch_duo(size_t item_count, const Type arr[], int search)
{
    int l = 0;
    int r = item_count - 1;
    while (r - l > 3) {

        int delta = (r - l) / 3;
        int m1 = l + delta;
        int m2 = r - delta;

        if (arr[m1] == search) return m1;
        if (arr[m2] == search) return m2;

        if (arr[m1] < search) {
            if (arr[m2] < search) {
                l = m2 + 1;
            }
            else {
                r = m2 - 1;
                l = m1 + 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            r = m1 - 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == search) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Of course, this approach can be done with more accesses per iteration (I'm testing three as well in my demo). There are some infinite loop issues if the `(l,r)` interval is very small (less then three), therefore, I finish the remaining items by a simple sequential search to keep the main iteration clean and simple.

I was doing my tests with Visual Studio 2017 C++ compiler.

I have several questions:

- Are there any other possible significant optimizations that could help the algorithm?
- Is my explanation of the improvement of the last algorithm correct? (is it really due to the fact that the CPU read in parallel two data items; therefore, he waits for it just once not twice like in the first algorithm).
- Are there any other comments about my code?

**CONCLUSION**

It seems that my assumptions regarding the architecture is wrong and the measurable slowdown in the case of MSVC compiler is caused mainly due to the bad condition order. Thanks all to contribute to this disscussion!

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. There is no immediate problem, but if you add more code we'll have to rollback the edit. Should your code be improved over time, post a follow-up question linking back to this one instead. Give it some time though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How did you measure the performance of your code (test code, hardware, compiler, etc.)? Without that it is impossible to get into optimization. Depending on chosen compiler I was sort of able to reproduce your results, see [this quick bench](http://quick-bench.com/cT8FjqPov65tetBZiSSEb5wlOHA)- for clang 7.0.0 the fancy algorithm is indeed faster. That being said with gcc the basic one is a lot faster (outperforming fancy algorithm in both clang and gcc).
With that in mind, you can optimize your algorithm for different array sizes quite easily (benchmarking on your specific setup), by choosing fastest of the 3 for specific sizes.

As far as the code is concerned, there are a couple of things you can improve.

You could rewrite your algorithms so that they accept iterators, just like all the algorithms from standard library, that will drastically improve their flexibility without added effort (and most probably without degrading performance, but you should measure it anyway).
Apart from that, you should avoid implicit conversions, e.g. here:

```
int r = item_count - 1;
```

You should also prefer to keep the bodies of your functions short, it's hard to understand what `binarySearch_duo` actually does (you could easily extract body of the loop etc). Also, avoid magic constants, where does the seven in: `while (r - l > 7) {` come from?

Edit: I've created one more benchmark for this, this time as proposed by OP, that is with huge array size (actually a vector) and made the access to the elements of the array random, see [here](http://quick-bench.com/_4FfE1Xo3gHe4gRGyerHm0hDBhE)- this time with gcc fancy version is as good as basic. The lesson should probably be: compiler is usually at least as smart as you are :).

Comment: You are using a small array that fits into the L2 cache (the CPU type is unknown). You can try to extend the size of the array to 1M to see the fancy code to win. However, it is still quite a small array and L2 cache misses do not occur significantly often. The number 7 is not important for the performance, it can be any small number lager than 3. I selected 7 since it approximately corresponds to one 64 cache line.

Comment: Not necessarily, gcc even after increasing the count of elements in the array to `10^6` elements produces better times for basic implementation. What I'm trying to say is that your results will vary depending on your benchmark and if you won't provide reliable way to measure performance, then it's tough to recommend further optimisations.

Comment: You are right. It is true that I did not specify the benchmark clearly here. I'll update the question.

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope it is more clear now. Thank you for your recommendations.

Comment: Concerning your benchmark - it is not large enough and also the queries into the array are not random.

Comment: There, made it huge and random. It's really awesome (at least for me) that gcc is still able to match performance of the fancy algorithm.

Comment: I did my tests with CLang and it is really almost the same. However, I would say that the result of the optimized version is as bad as the basic one with CLang. With MSVC 14.1 I get much better results with optimized code. Interesting, I have to investigate this. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

## Prefetch version does nothing with optimizer turned on.

Since you are not using m1 and m2, compiler will eliminate them. You get identical codegen see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/wahP5j)

## Branchs

Rearranging the conditions appear to speed up the code by 20%, making basic case almost the same as duo version. Note the conditions are already swapped for duo version, this may explain some of its performance. It appears the less than branch is more common and allow other condition to be skipped.

```
if (arr[m] < search) l = m + 1;
else if (arr[m] == search) return m;
else r = m - 1;
```

Comment: True, I agree. The main issue here is why MSVC compiler is so bad on the basic version when compared to CLang/Gcc or when compared to the duo version (and note that it is only the case of MSVC on out of the CPU data).

Comment: @RadimBača oh I just had an interesting observation. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, you are right! The order of the conditions seems to cause significant slowdown. There are still some questions left but thank you for the observation.

Comment: The careful calculation of mean isn't a performance hack - it's to ensure correctness (avoiding overflow).

Comment: See [The curious case of Binary Search — The famous bug that remained undetected for 20 years](https://thebittheories.com/the-curious-case-of-binary-search-the-famous-bug-that-remained-undetected-for-20-years-973e89fc212?gi=314801aff944), for instance.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to "Are there any other possible significant optimizations that could help the algorithm?"

I don't know, and it may have no effect at all, or even reduce performance, but I would like to know if reducing the apparent number of array operations improves performance, for example change

```
    if (arr[m1] == search) return m1;
    if (arr[m2] == search) return m2;

    if (arr[m1] < search) {
        if (arr[m2] < search) {
```

to

```
    Type am1 = arr[m1], am2 = arr[m2];
    if (am1 == search) return m1;
    if (am2 == search) return m2;

    if (am1 < search) {
        if (am2 < search) {
```

Apart from that, with regard to "Are there any other comments about my code?" could I suggest using say `left` and `right` instead of `l` and `r` as variable names. `l` is very easy to mistake for `1`!